# Linking libraries CMake

Tags: c++, unit-testing, cmake

I'm not sure whether the title is correct, but anyway:

I'm writing the project with `boost` and `eigen3` libraries, further I would like to test CMake. So far I've written everything in one .cpp file, the header is like:

```
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/matrix.hpp>
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/io.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include "eigen/Eigen/Dense"

#define BOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE Hello
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>

#include <cmath>
#include <boost/timer/timer.hpp>
#include <fstream>
```

Further I added some boost unit tests in my "main" function in the following way

```
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(universeInOrder)
{
  Eigen::Matrix3d m;
  m << 0, 1, 2,  
       3, 4, 5,
       6, 7, 8;
  BOOST_CHECK(Min(m) == 1);
}
```

where `Min` is a separate function returning the lowest coeff. of matrix.
In my directory I have both `FindEigen3.CMake` and `FindBoost.CMake` files. I also have `CMakeLists.txt` file with the code:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.0)
project (hello)
find_package (Eigen3 3.3 REQUIRED NO_MODULE)
add_executable (hello hello.cpp)
target_link_libraries (hello Eigen3::Eigen)

enable_testing()
```

I'm running

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
```

and there are no errors, everything is ok.

To run the program I use

```
g++ -I /home/fdhd/Documents/boost/ file-name.cpp -lboost_unit_test_framework -lboost_timer -o file-name
```

And here is my question - can I avoid linking `boost` in that command above and plug in into `CMakeLists.txt` file and run just 
`g++ file-name.cpp` , 
so that it will work because everything is in `CMakeLists` file?

Any ideas? I think that the solution must be just behind the corner, but I can't really see it.

Thanks!

Comment: _"To run the program I use ..."_ Wait, doesn't CMake already do that for you??

Comment: To tell the truth I'm not sure, if yes how do I "run" the program afterwards?

Comment: That may be considered silly, but I'm kind of lost

Comment: The command line you posted, doesn't _run the program_, but calls the compiler to compile `file-name.cpp` and link it as an executable target. To call the executable just type `./file-name` in the directory it was created.

Comment: Yes, I know this, but I think there is really no CMake here, is it?

Comment: I thought that instead of using g++ there is some nice method to use CMake to compile and run the program

Comment: Maybe you are looking for this: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_test.html

Comment: You're not using cmake correctly - cmake generates (amongst others) makefiles, which means you type `make`, not `g++ ...` to build the program

Comment: You `CMakeLists` file should be named `CMakeLists.txt` not `CMakeLists.txt.cmake`

Comment: Yes, sorry, there is a type, its names `CMakeLists.txt`. But apart from that it return no errors, when I run `make` in `build` directory it says that it is done, but there is no file which i can run with `./file-name`

Comment: You configured CMake to build an executable named hello not file-name.

Answer (score 0):

> To run the program I use

Nop, that's not the cmake idiomatic way to run/test your program. Since you have **enable_testing()**, cmake already has a custom target for you to run your binary. According to the CTest [wiki](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake/Testing_With_CTest), all you need is to type make test after adding **add_test** function in you CMakeLists.txt. More or less like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.0)
project (hello)
find_package (Eigen3 3.3 REQUIRED NO_MODULE)
add_executable (hello hello.cpp)
target_link_libraries (hello Eigen3::Eigen)

enable_testing()

add_test(test hello)
```